# How to open the downloaded file once download is complete in angular?

Tags: angular, rest, file, http, download

My requirement is to download a file and open the downloaded file once the download is complete in angular. I m able to download the file but I m stuck with opening the downloaded file. Is there a way to achieve this in angular 8 or above?

Comment: What kind of file are we talking here ?

Comment: it can be a type of any format like .txt/.xml/.json/.doc. Once downloaded, it should be opened in the Systems default editor like notepad/gedit based on the Operating System.

Comment: I dont think that is possible. The user has to execute files on their own system. Else it would be way to easy install viruses on users machines.

Answer (score 0):

Define "open the file" If you mean open the file in user system (e.g open picture with paint.exe, or open *.xlsx file with MS Excel) then that is out of your control and after download the user must take action (either manually or pre-configure default system actions). However if you mean to download the file and present the file contents (e.g show image inside browser) then that implementation depends on what kind of file type are we talking about and how it should be presented.